# How to add include directory to Visual C++ Express 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ide

Include directories aren't configurable via Tools/Options anymore. I see no way to do that via Solution Properties also. I have set INCLUDE environment variable, restarted VS but cl.exe (rc.exe really) still misses a header file.

```
fatal error RC1015: cannot open include file 'winres.h'.

C:> echo %INCLUDE%                                 
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Platform SDK\Include\mfc

C:> ls "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Platform SDK\Include\mfc\WINRES.H"
WINRES.H <-- it exists
```

Comment: It's there in the project properties.

Comment: The error is from rc.exe, not cl.exe.  Using an ancient version of mfc to work around the license restrictions is not a great idea.  If you don't want to pay for your tools then consider the open source offerings.

Comment: I'd be glad to get a newer version of Platform SDK.